# If $L$ is a $CFL$, then why isn't $L^*$ also $CFL$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

I was studying closure properties of CFLs and I came across this. I want to understand why $L^*$ is not a CFL, can anyone explain me in depth with simple examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, if $L$ is context-free then so is $L^*$. The easiest way to see that is using context-free grammar. Every context-free language $L$ is generated by some context-free grammar $G$ with starting symbol $S$. Now add a new starting symbol $S'$ and the productions $S' \to S'S|\epsilon$. The new grammar $G'$ is also context-free and generates $L^*$.